# Making javascript function more shorter

Tags: javascript, extjs

Ok so I know this heading may be not properly defined, but I am basically interested in making one of my javascript functions in ExtJs 6 more shorter or efficient, here is the code I am talking about
this function is for an on list item tap, its using itemTpl

```
onMylist2ItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    var company_name = record.get('name');
    var license_idval = record.get('license_id');
    var start_date = record.get('start_date');
    var expiry_date = record.get('expiry_date');
    var product_name = record.get('product_name');
    var mac = record.get('mac_address');
    var server_url = record.get('server_url');
    var end = record.get('end_date');
    var duration = record.get('duration');
    var feature = record.get('feature');
    var invoice = record.get('invoice_number');
    var view = Ext.getCmp('mainview');
    view.setActiveItem(2);
    Ext.getCmp('name').setValue(company_name);
    Ext.getCmp('product_name').setValue(product_name);
    Ext.getCmp('mac').setValue(mac);
    Ext.getCmp('server').setValue(server_url);
    Ext.getCmp('start').setValue(start_date);
    Ext.getCmp('end').setValue(end);
    Ext.getCmp('duration').setValue(duration);
    Ext.getCmp('expiry').setValue(expiry_date);
    Ext.getCmp('features').setValue(feature);
    Ext.getCmp('license_id').setValue(license_idval);
    Ext.getCmp('invoice').setValue(invoice);
},
```

it is really long, is there a way I can shorten it, make it more efficient
thanks

Comment: tried using dataview as a replacement for 'var view...', it didnt work though

Comment: Eliminate all the temporary variables that are only ever referenced once.

Comment: Are all those components (like `Ext.getCmp('name')`) represent form input elements?

Comment: yes RomanPerekhrest they do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing variables used to assign values from record and set values directly as shown below

```
onMylist2ItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    var view = Ext.getCmp('mainview');
    view.setActiveItem(2);
    Ext.getCmp('name').setValue(record.get('name'));
    Ext.getCmp('product_name').setValue(record.get('product_name'));
    Ext.getCmp('mac').setValue(record.get('mac_address'));
    Ext.getCmp('server').setValue(record.get('server_url'));
    Ext.getCmp('start').setValue(record.get('start_date'));
    Ext.getCmp('end').setValue(record.get('end_date'));
    Ext.getCmp('duration').setValue(record.get('duration'));
    Ext.getCmp('expiry').setValue(record.get('expiry_date'));
    Ext.getCmp('features').setValue(record.get('feature'));
    Ext.getCmp('license_id').setValue(record.get('license_id'));
    Ext.getCmp('invoice').setValue(record.get('invoice_number'));
},
```

Comment: i think your answer is the most viable, easiest to implement the other proposed by Ali Mamedov wont work as the variables are not all the same name, so you cant just say for (i in arr) ....

Comment: I dont know why I bothered even adding variables storing the record

Comment: This is still a poor way to do it. You should either use databinding or `form.setValues()`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
var FIELDS = {
  "name": "name",
  "start_date": "start",
  // ...
};
```

and then

```
Object.keys(FIELDS).forEach(function(key) {
  Ext.getCmp(FIELDS[key]).setValue(record.get(key));
});
```

Comment: mmmm let me try that

Comment: Something what i would recommend because of same looking key names. Nice.